# Can I uninstall Bing completely from Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, bing

Windows 8.1 is a pain, but Bing is a bigger pain, and I would love to remove the annoyance as it serves no purpose for me, except possibly for Microsoft. If I uninstall it completely, will it cause any secret problems later and annoyances, and have some affect on other applications?

I would love to get rid of it completely, as I only use Google and Internet Explorer as my browser.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply, I checked the other direction, but I am non the wiser.

Comment: Bing is just an app. And if Windows is a pain for you, why don't you try Linux?

Answer (score 0):

The only change that should happen is you will be unable to search Bing.

Comment: Thanks SLHCK, but I am non-the-wiser as the answer your directed me to was a bit confusing.  The Questions I asked: "If I uninstall Bing completely, will it effect any other apps within WIN 8?"  I noticed one reply that said it could possibly effect Media Player and IE, but there was no definite answer to my question.  Therefore, can I uninstall BING without any consequences?  Because the other question/answers you directed me to didn't answer my question.  I assume that nobody really knows.  Thanks with regards.